# How can I make sure that I have ProGuard in my android studio?

Tags: android

How Can I make sure that I have **ProGuard** in the android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `build.gradle` file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Additional options:

> You can also add ProGuard files to the getDefaultProguardFile
>   directive for all release builds or as part of the productFlavor
>   settings in the build.gradle file to customize the settings applied to
>   build variants. This example adds the proguard-rules-new.pro to the
>   proguardFiles directive and the other-rules.pro file to the flavor2
>   product flavor.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-new.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
    }
    flavor2 {
        proguardFile 'other-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/tools/help/proguard.html).

Edit: Note that `runProgruard` is [deprecated](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) and has been replaced with `minifyEnabled`. Use the above example.

> DSL/API changes: Renamed a few properties to make things more
>   consistent. BuildType.runProguard                 ->  minifyEnabled

Comment: When I use the code in **build.gradle** (Of Course I use runproguard Instead of the minifyEnabled), I can compile my code successfully. Does this mean that I have ProGuard in my android studio?

Comment: @java See my edit. Do not use `runProguard`. Use `minifyEnabled`.